# React setState not merging all changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### EDIT - I can't vote for my own answer at the moment but this turned out to be a reference/immutability issue - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60189228/11602055

this one has me completely stumped!

I'm getting some data from my server and applying it to my state, but some of the properties I'm applying to the state don't migrate to the state after setState has completed...

I've tried everything I can think of regarding this, I'm reading the final state as part of the callback from setState to ensure I'm getting the state after setState has completed so it's nothing to do with setState being Async in nature.

Have attempted the following -

- use a blank object, save new props to that object and then return that.
- apply each property one at a time in separate setState calls inside an outer loop on the keys
- return Object.assign({},this.state,data);
- return {...data};
- return {...this.state,...data};
- await setState(...);
- setState(data)

I've got a couple of nested state properties but this is affecting root properties of the state object...

See code/output/end state below, note for example that eventColour has not propagated through the setState action to the final state... (same applies for iconCls...)

Help please?...

Code:

```
getJobDetail = async function (){

    // get data from server
    let response = await window.fetch("/event/events?id="+this.props.job,{cache: "no-cache", credentials: "same-origin"});

    // parse returned data
    let data = await response.json();

    // couple of minor data manipulation exercises
    if (data.tempToFeedback!==null){
        data.toFeedback=data.tempToFeedback;
    }
    if (data.tempSwitchNotes!==null){
        data.switchingNotes=data.tempSwitchNotes;
    }
    if (data.editedName!==null){
        data.name=data.editedName;
    }
    if (data.fileList!==null){
        data.fileList=JSON.parse(data.fileList);
    }

    // merge all recieved data onto state
    this.setState(currentState=>{

        for (let key of Object.keys(data)){
            console.log("setting " + key + " from "+currentState[key]+" to " + data[key]);
            currentState[key]=data[key];
        }

        return currentState;
    }
    ,
        ()=>{
            // output new state on callback (doesn't include everything which was merged in...)
            console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state)))
        }
    )

}
```

Console output during setState

```
setting id from undefined to 214793


setting tnccJobsID from undefined to 214793
 setting startDate from undefined to 2020-02-12T08:00:00.000Z
 setting endDate from undefined to 2020-02-12T09:00:00.000Z
 setting resourceId from undefined to 99921
 setting FKusers from undefined to 99999
 setting previousJob from undefined to null
 setting isInfoBooking from undefined to 0
 setting isCSP from undefined to null
 setting isDAR from undefined to 0
 setting hasStarted from undefined to 0
 setting hasEnded from undefined to 0
 setting isCancelled from undefined to 0
 setting FKtogaGroups from undefined to 12327
 setting currentStep from undefined to 0
 setting adjustedFKjobTypes from undefined to null
 setting FKjobTypes from undefined to 23
 setting lastUpdated from undefined to null
 setting name from undefined to undefined
 setting jobTypeID from undefined to 23
 setting eventType from undefined to Operational Release
 setting eventColor from undefined to orange
 setting eventStyle from undefined to colored
 setting iconCls from undefined to fas fa-plane-departure
 setting weight from undefined to 1
 setting northDesk from undefined to 1
 setting southDesk from undefined to 0
 setting switchOutState from undefined to 1
 setting feedbackState from undefined to 1
 setting feedbackRequired from undefined to 0
 setting demandAtRisk from undefined to null
 setting demandAtRiskApproved from undefined to null
 setting runwaySteps from undefined to [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
 setting startStep from undefined to 4
 setting endStep from undefined to 5
 setting fileList from undefined to 
 setting outageList from undefined to [object Object]
 setting toFeedback from undefined to undefined
 setting switchingNotes from undefined to undefined
```

Final state as read out in callback

```
updateData: {}
fileDrawer: null
fileUploading: null
showJobDetailModal: false
id: 214793
tnccJobsID: 214793
startDate: "2020-02-12T08:00:00.000Z"
endDate: "2020-02-12T09:00:00.000Z"
resourceId: 99921
FKusers: 99999
previousJob: null
isInfoBooking: 0
isCSP: null
isDAR: 0
hasStarted: 0
hasEnded: 0
isCancelled: 0
FKtogaGroups: 12327
currentStep: 0
adjustedFKjobTypes: null
FKjobTypes: 23
lastUpdated: null
jobTypeID: 23
eventType: "Operational Release"
eventStyle: "colored"
weight: 1
northDesk: 1
southDesk: 0
switchOutState: 1
feedbackState: 1
feedbackRequired: 0
demandAtRisk: null
demandAtRiskApproved: null
runwaySteps: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
startStep: 4
endStep: 5
fileList: []
outageList: [{…}]
__proto__: Object
```

Image formats as well!

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf8wH.png)

[setState Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmXzM.png)

[state as read in callback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fvAX.png)

Demo version of code with data in it:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';


export const JobView = class JobView extends React.PureComponent{



    render(){


            return null;

    }

}


export const JobDetails = class JobDetails extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            // jobData:null,
            updateData:{},


        }


        this.getJobDetail = this.getJobDetail.bind(this);

        this.setState = this.setState.bind(this);


    }

    componentDidMount(){





        this.getJobDetail();


        }


    getJobDetail = async function (){

        // get data from server
        // let response = await window.fetch("/event/events?id="+this.props.job,{cache: "no-cache", credentials: "same-origin"});

        // parse returned data
        // let data = await response.json();
        let data = JSON.parse('{"id":5267,"tnccJobsID":5267,"startDate":"2020-02-12T08:00:00.000Z","endDate":"2020-02-12T09:00:00.000Z","resourceId":99921,"FKusers":99999,"previousJob":null,"isInfoBooking":0,"isCSP":null,"isDAR":0,"hasStarted":null,"hasEnded":null,"isCancelled":null,"FKtogaGroups":2830,"currentStep":1,"adjustedFKjobTypes":null,"FKjobTypes":1,"lastUpdated":"2020-01-21T22:30:43.000Z","name":"OCKER HILL 132KV BUS SECTION 120 .","jobTypeID":1,"eventType":"Operational Release","eventColor":"orange","eventStyle":"colored","iconCls":"fas fa-plane-departure","weight":1,"northDesk":1,"southDesk":0,"switchOutState":1,"feedbackState":1,"feedbackRequired":0,"demandAtRisk":null,"demandAtRiskApproved":null,"runwaySteps":[{"step":1,"active":{"icon":"loading","text":"Planning"},"isLast":false,"completed":{"icon":"bars","text":"Planned"}},{"step":2,"active":{"icon":"loading","text":"Negotiating TSC"},"isLast":false,"completed":{"icon":"file-done","text":"TSC Recieved"}},{"step":3,"active":{"icon":"loading","text":"Awaiting Allocation"},"isLast":false,"completed":{"icon":"user","text":"Allocated"}},{"step":4,"active":{"icon":"loading","text":"Waiting to Start"},"isLast":false,"completed":{"icon":"user","text":"Started"}},{"step":5,"active":{"icon":"loading","text":"Switching In Progress"},"isLast":false,"completed":{"icon":"api","text":"Switched"}},{"step":6,"active":{"icon":"loading","text":"Releasing To Safety"},"isLast":true,"completed":{"icon":"check","text":"Released To Safety"}}],"startStep":4,"endStep":6,"fullHistory":[{"time":"2019-11-23T22:58:44.000Z","entryTo":"No","entryFrom":0,"changedBy":"System","message":"hasEnded Changed"},{"time":"2019-11-23T22:58:44.000Z","entryTo":"No","entryFrom":0,"changedBy":"System","message":"hasStarted Changed"},{"time":"2019-11-23T22:58:44.000Z","entryTo":"No","entryFrom":0,"changedBy":"System","message":"isCancelled Changed"},{"time":"2019-11-25T23:03:12.000Z","entryTo":"No","entryFrom":0,"changedBy":"System","message":"hasEnded Changed"},{"time":"2019-11-25T23:03:12.000Z","entryTo":"No","entryFrom":0,"changedBy":"System","message":"hasStarted Changed"},{"time":"2019-11-25T23:03:12.000Z","entryTo":"No","entryFrom":0,"changedBy":"System","message":"isCancelled Changed"},{"time":"2019-11-28T22:59:03.000Z","entryTo":"No","entryFrom":0,"changedBy":"System","message":"hasEnded Changed"},{"time":"2019-11-28T22:59:03.000Z","entryTo":"No","entryFrom":0,"changedBy":"System","message":"hasStarted Changed"},{"time":"2019-11-28T22:59:03.000Z","entryTo":"No","entryFrom":0,"changedBy":"System","message":"isCancelled Changed"},{"time":"2020-01-13T22:39:10.000Z","entryTo":0,"entryFrom":null,"changedBy":"System","message":"isDAR Changed"}],"fileList":"[]","outageList":[]}');

        // console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        // couple of minor data manipulation exercises
        if (data.tempToFeedback!==null){
            data.toFeedback=data.tempToFeedback;
        }
        if (data.tempSwitchNotes!==null){
            data.switchingNotes=data.tempSwitchNotes;
        }
        if (data.editedName!==null){
            data.name=data.editedName;
        }
        if (data.fileList!==null){
            data.fileList=JSON.parse(data.fileList);
        }

        // merge all recieved data onto state
        await this.setState((currentState,props)=>{
            let newState = {}
            for (let key of Object.keys(data)){
                console.log("setting " + key + " from "+currentState[key]+" to " + data[key]);
                newState[key]=data[key];
            }
            console.log(newState);
            return newState;
        }


        ,
            ()=>{
                // output new state on callback (doesn't include everything which was merged in...)

                console.log(this.state);
            }
        )

    }





    render(){
        return JSON.stringify(this.state);
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add the code into your question, not images. If the images go away this question becomes meaningless.

Comment: Done, apologies :)

Answer (score 1):

So turns out I'm being stupid! but for anyone else who comes across this issue, I had a part of my render function that went something like this :

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={prop1:"first value"};
}
render(){
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.prop1))) // "first value"
  let easyToAccessState = this.state;
  easyToAccessState.prop1 = "another value";
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.prop1))) // "another value"
}
```

To avoid this, create a copy of state into the easyToAccessState variable :

```
render(){
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.prop1))) // "first value"
  let easyToAccessState = {...this.state}; // COPIES STATE
  easyToAccessState.prop1 = "another value";
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.prop1))) // "first value"
}
```

**Obviously ideally no changes should be being made to anything during render... that's something I'm taking away from this and am going to move the recalculation of prop1 to put it properly into state and use it correctly in the first place...**

These things are sent to test us... immutability and referencing eh!

Answer (score 0):

In `setState` try to return `{ ...currentState }`

Answer (score 0):

try to set state so

```
    this.setState({...this.state, ...data},
        () => {
            // output new state on callback (doesn't include everything which was merged in...)
            console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state)))
        }
    )
```

Comment: Same issue, no change :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.setState((currentState, props)=>{
    let newState = {};
        for (let key of Object.keys(data)){
            newState[key] = data[key];
            console.log("setting " + key + " from "+currentState[key]+" to " + data[key]);
        }

    return newState;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately still results in the same result :(

Comment: Put await before setState and then console to check if you are printing it before async completes.

Comment: just tried that myself thinking maybe I'd been a complete eejit... doesn't change the result though :(

Comment: That is fine, it should work that way but I think a working code environment will help people here to help you back in more efficient way. Otherwise this kind of prediction game goes on until one hit bulls eye.

Comment: Could you please give 'response' object here for me to try in my environment.

Comment: just trying to get that down to a comment length for you :P

Comment: where is JSON.stringify?

Comment: Lol Ok, try to post it as answer.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/18Zk3iAYme00HfSthD3sisfOe8IUSx30Pit61xieIH28/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: have also added to question as running example which still isn't working for me

Comment: Eugh, ok, so that snippet of code i've put on my question actually works... now i'm just trying to figure out how!...

Comment: Thats great. If my code snippet helped you please upvote.

Comment: Turns out it was completely unrelated, see my answer above... :(

Comment: Got it, you had reference issue and completely unrelated to questions context. Cheers and good job.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, first time on here, so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not need for you to merge `currentState` with the new state - by default state merges the new values into the old one

Have you tried simply:

```
this.setState(data);

// Instead of
// merge all received data onto state
// await this.setState((currentState,props)=>{
//       let newState = {}
//       for (let key of Object.keys(data)){
//           console.log("setting " + key + " from "+currentState[key]+" to " + data[key]);
//           newState[key]=data[key];
//       }
//       console.log(newState);
//       return newState;
//   }
```

You are trying to do some of React's work.

Also, I don't think you need `await` in front of `this.setState`. Although `setState` is [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous) "don’t rely on this.state to reflect the new value immediately after calling setState" - [details here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Just tried this, think I started back here when everything went awry!, unfortunately has the same result at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

You should try this `this.setState(data,()=>console.log(this.state))`

see working code [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-easley-n434y)

it also works if your initial state define empty after getting a response you can setState your data